# Аргумент командной строки

Tags: c

Объявил подобным образом

```
void main(int argc)
```

Использую в программе так:

```
for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("Argument %d\n", i);
}
```

Вызываю так:

```
C:\Users\Elvin\source\repos\atoi\Debug>atoi.exe 10
```

Хочу чтобы вывелось 10 раз, но выходит только два раза.

Comment: Странно, в первой редакции до правки была даже указана метка argv, но в main вы  "забыли" этот аргумент. Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Параметр `argc` это колличество аргументов, их два - имя программы и первый аргумент 10.
Но сами аргументы не объявлены в `main`.

Объявите их одним из способов, которые идентичны:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
int main (int argc, char** argv)
```

Используйте значение `int args = atoi (argv[1]);` вместо `argc` в цикле.

PS Избегайте объявлять тип возврата `void` из `main`, это не обязательно поддерживается на всех платформах.

Answer (score 1):

=) Это не очень похоже на С

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Error\n");
    return -1;
  }
  int count = atoi(argv[1]);
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    printf("%i\n", i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Тут argc содержит количество аргументов. А argv указывает на массив С строк.